# Using remmina to remote into an ubuntu desktop on another netowrk

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remmina

I have 2 ubuntu machines (1 laptop, 1 desktop). I want to log in to the desktop from the laptop when I am either or the same network or not.

The desktop, as suggested in a few places, seems to have all the correct "sharing" options turned on.
[image]

Additionally, I have remmina (1.4.7) installed.

I know the IP of my desktop (fwiw, I used: [showmyipaddress.eu](https://www.showmyipaddress.eu/).

On my laptop I also have file sharing, screen sharing and remote login turned on (this is probably overkill).

I also have remmina installed (currently 1.4.7).

Now, I can connect to the desktop using the "local" name:
[image]

But, when I try to use the same method, but change the local name to the **external** IP address, I get "unable to connect to the VNC server".

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: There is a difference between local IP addresses and Internet IP addresses. You have not told us how your network is configured, but I suspect the Remmina client and server are on the same network. A public IP address such as showmyipaddress.eu gives you is no help. Find the local IP address of the server (under Settings/network) and try that.

Comment: @Jos Yes, but wouldn't I need the remote IP address if I were on another network ont he laptop?

Comment: @Jos I am able to connect via the local IP address as well, just not the remote IP address.

Comment: You haven't told us if you are behind a router or firewall. If behind a router, it probably won't process packets that come in on the public interface but from the inside LAN, as a security measure. You may need to connect from outside your LAN to make it work. And then the router needs to forward packets on the VNC port to your server.

Comment: You need to tell your router, to do a NetworkAddressTranslation for your external to your internal address and most optimal only choose a Port Forward on the specific port you are using. Your router needs to know which machine should get the packages, if this specific port is opened from the Internet.

Comment: Additionally check if the local firewall is blcoking your port. check if UFW is active, if it is open the port.

Comment: I suggest connecting over ssh. Get an ssh connection set up and working, then use the connect over ssh options in remmina.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you. I've been trying to find a good guide. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: I have the same problem on 18.04. Both machines are in the same LAN. Attempting to use any interface other than "localhost" (which I used to try running both the client and the server on the same machine - and this works) results in the "unable to connect" error. Tried this on 2 different wireless networks: same result.

Answer (score 0):

To access your desktop from you laptop you can use the SSH protocol. It will give you access to the terminal.

You can follow [this](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-openssh) instructions to properly set it up.

If you want to login in a graphical interface mode you need another protocol as VNC (port 5900) or RDP (port 3389). You can see instrunctions for VNC [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) and RDP [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-protocol-using-xrdp-on-ubuntu-22-04)

But you need to make sure that the protocol you're using has it's port exposed globally (as you want access over the internet). You can do this by using the following command:
`netstat -tuln`
(You may need to install it first `sudo apt install net-tools`)

For example, for SSH (port 22) make sure it shows `tcp ... 0.0.0.0:22 ... LISTEN`

For example, after you installed the SSH server on your desktop and allowed it to listen globally you can access through Remmina by:

1. [Adding a new connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzQdH.png)
2. [Add SSH connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO5tX.png)